# iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: iptables

```
root@OpenWrt:/man/ipk# iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "instagram" -j DROP
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
root@OpenWrt:/man/ipk#
```

**Can anyone suggest why this isn't working?**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if the netfilter string module has been compiled into the kernel, or as a module, or not. Some years ago, and due to the "string" module's potential high CPU usage, it was not available by default in Ubuntu kernels. In more recent years years (I don't recall when, exactly) it is available, as a module, by default. The way to check for your Ubuntu kernel is to search for it in the kernel configuration module. Example:

```
doug@s17:~$ uname -a
Linux s17 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
doug@s17:~$ grep -i NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STRING /boot/config-4.15.0-36-generic
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STRING=m
```

So, it is there as a module on my system. And the command loads fine for me:

```
doug@s17:~$ sudo iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "instagram" -j DROP
doug@s17:~$ sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 210 packets, 15763 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "instagram" ALGO name bm TO 65535

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 141 packets, 36585 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```